# how to write remember me feature in Rspec-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails, sorcery

I use the sorcery gem to complete the login feature,and I have used the "remember me" feature.But I don't know how to write the test code with Rspec.I found the Capybara gem but don't know how to use it.

**what I want to test is when I check the remember me box to login,and then logout with the admin username and password what I login last time,if not there is no any value.**

can anybody give me some hint?thank you very much.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You could have 2 tests. I don't know exactly how your site works (or how remember me function works), so here is the basic idea.

Test 1: Remembers

1. Visit home page
2. Check "remember me"
3. Fill out form
4. Click login
5. Click logout
6. Visit home page
7. Click login
8. expect(page).to have_content "You have logged in"

Test 2: Does not remember

1. Visit home page
2. Fill out form
3. Click login
4. Click logout
5. Visit home page
6. Click login
7. expect(page).to have_content "You must enter a name and password"

To go to the homepage with Capybara, use visit:

`visit '/'`

To check a box:

`check 'remember_me'`

You'll need to fill out the form and click on buttons.

Here is the Capybara reference: https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#using-capybara-with-rspec